# svn Authentication realm in AIX even after passing id/password

Tags: svn, authorization, aix

Iam getting "Authorization Realm" error from one particular AIX server. Iam able to access svn from other similar servers.

```
>svn list
Authentication realm: <https://aedc.extra.aexp.com:443> Authorization Realm
Password for 'useridx':
Authentication realm: <https://aedc.extra.aexp.com:443> Authorization Realm
Username: useridx
Password for 'useridx':
Authentication realm: <https://aedc.extra.aexp.com:443> Authorization Realm
Username:
```

I have tried removing .subversion folder from home folder. It does the same thing again after adding the security key.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, but just the AuthName set in your server's config. Contact an administrator and ask him to check the server's logs.

Most likely, you just enter an invalid password.